# Getting value in textField from UIPopOverController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a text field and a button.On clicking the button I am getting a UIpopoverController with table View. The moment I select any row of that popover,the popover is dismissed and it should be auto populated in text field. I am able to get the popover but I am not able to get that selected row value into the text field. How can I do it?

Comment: You should review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?s=2|2.3658